# WordPress trigger standard post list rendering

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to programmatically trigger the standard displaying post list from a custom WP_Query, just like a "category" menu item does?
To clarify:
i'm not looking for plugins like [List category posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) that do the work but with a custom built-in template..
I need the wp's(theme's) standard post list rendering loop to be triggered !
Thanks!

Comment: You need just list of post links? Or you need something more sophisticated and I didn't got it?

Comment: I need a way to *just* render a list of posts (from a custom `WP_Query`) with the current theme's archive template:  
I *guess* that it would be enough to trigger (or include) the `[theme_dir]/archive.php` with some global var valued with the results of the custom `WP_Query` ?

Comment: i mean the same rendering that happens when you click a `menu->category` item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it..
inside a shortcode's function, or in a function that act ajax style, put a code like that:

```
global  $wp_query;
$cat = $_GET['categoria'];
$wp_query->init();
$wp_query->query(array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'category_name' => $cat 
  ));
get_template_part( 'blog', 'columns' );
wp_reset_query();
die();
```

the `get_template_part` arguments are theme dependent and can be desumed from php template names from theme's root directory.
in this case wp will call `[theme's_dir]/blog-columns.php`..
i reccomend the [lecture](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) @Michal reccomended me

Answer (score 0):

Put this code where ever you need to render list of post from category "example_category_slug",  (or any other taxonomy).

```
$wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'category','term'=>'example_category_slug');
$myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
$article_count = $myquery->post_count;
echo "<ul>";
if ($article_count){
  while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
  echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
  endwhile;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

or use simpler query, like `$myquery = new WP_Query ('cat= 11, 9');` for cat ids, or any other [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
But while choosing where to put it, consider [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) as a set of rules which template file is right to use.

If you need a list of categoires insted post use wp_list_categories

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'show_option_all'    => '',
 'orderby'            => 'name',
 'order'              => 'ASC',
 'style'              => 'list'
); 
wp_list_categories($args);
?>
```

ful ref. in [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: Michal, thank you, but this code will render only a list of post-title-link to the relative post page.. I need to render the posts with the theme's category-page-template ! as i said : the same rendering that happens when you click a ``menu->category`` item.. i will now dig into [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to see if i find some hint there

Comment: You need links to category pages, which is archive for one category only?

Comment: I need: having a custom WP_Query as you did in the code, let the theme render it as it would do, with its own templates, for an archive page

Comment: Thank you,i found many hints in [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and i got my feet wet with custom archive/post templates and that's great, very good intro... but i couldn't get to my point.. i try to reformulate the question pointing the result i need to achieve : i'd like to render the active-theme's archive-page with a custom search-form before, so to display below the results of a custom-query made with the search-form's parameters..

Comment: by before you mean passed as post arguments (if so what it'll be)?

Comment: sorry, i meant 'above': the user shouold always see the form above and the paginated theme's-archive below alltogether, and yes, the form should post arguments and refresh page..